# What is the name of the sound that a coin makes when hitting coins collected in a jar?

Tags: single-word-requests

If I drop a coin into a jar half-filled with coins, what is the common name of that sound? I.e. not the formal name, but the name that would be used in everyday talk.

As I understand it (based on translation from my language), the following words are "correct":

ring, jingle, ping, ding, chime, ting, chink, twang, ring out, clang, clunk

However, I need to know which one of those (or maybe some other?) is the best fit for the given case.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

This can usually be called [**clink**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/clink).

> A light, sharp ringing sound, as of glass or metal.

It should be noted though that it isn't just limited to coins and, as such, can be used for multiple purposes. However, for what you describe, it could possibly be one of the better words.

For what it's worth, there's a sound-effect by the title [clink of coins](http://soundsilk.com/clink-of-coins-sound-effect/).

Comment: I did some research and that got me wondering, is this sound name (clink) more associated with doing a toast (where glasses meet) than with coins?

Comment: @LukasKalinski - It's associated with both. You might as well ask whether "crack" means the sound of a stick breaking or the sound of thunder. Lots of words are used in multiple situations.

Comment: The onomatopoeia can be softened by using "chink", which is more like the sound of coin landing on layers already there, than the "clink" of a coin on glass? If I hear "clink", I'm afraid my piggy-bank is empty :( .

Comment: I think *chink* is closer (more 'ringing') (also for two glasses together "chinka chinka").  If the coins are first into the jar then I'd hear them '*jingling*'.

Comment: As @RobinBetts on *chink*, so do I.

Comment: Or the similar **tink**.

Comment: @RobinBetts As pointed out further down the page, "chink" is a racial slur in the US.

Comment: @AzorAhai   Some words become so loaded in cultures in which they have been employed to offend, that no matter in what context, or with which intent, they are spoken, they become offensive or disgusting  in their own right. I think that is a shame, but if this word is one of those in  your culture, please accept my apology.

Comment: @RobinBetts No problem. Just sharing knowledge about English.

Comment: Clink and tlink are a good pair here. Around my D&D group, "clink" has become a verb in its own right, meaning "drop a coin into [a jar]" - for instance, "I'd make a comment there, but I'd have to clink the pun jar".

Comment: "chink" is not a racial slur unless the speaker is talking about one or more persons.  If I talk about the "chink of a coin" or a "chink in my armor," that is not a racial slur.  Language changes fast enough; no need to change it faster merely to avoid offending someone who is being unreasonable.

Comment: I've also heard clink, but I've usually seen it spelled `klink`.

Answer (score 33):

Along with "clink" there is also the word [plink](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/plink).

> a short, sharp, metallic or ringing sound.

I feel, from my view, this is more closely associated with metal on metal contact sounds. I initially heard the word in the context of sport or leisure shooting, "plinking" is the act of going out and shooting steel targets or even small aluminum cans. A small "plink" sound is heard each time a target is hit. Though much lower pitched, this is the same type of sound when tossing coins in a jar.

Answer (score 18):

My first thought was "chink", that's how I'd describe the initial sound of one coin hitting others in a jar if there was no further movement of either the new coin or the ones already there.

Comment: I'd caution use of this word. In some cultures (parts of the United States, at least), this is used as a racial slur.

Comment: @maxathousand   'Chink' is a perfectly respectable word as listed in the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/31777?rskey=bkuNPH&result=3&isAdvanced=false#eid). It might as well be said that one should never use a whole list of common words merely because some people have chosen to abuse the English language.

Comment: @NigelJ "*[O]ne should never use a whole list of common words merely because some people have chosen to abuse the English language.*" I'd say this is absolutely right. This is why I do not call my in-law's dog a bitch, even though it's precisely accurate. I was just pointing out that use of this word might unintentionally cause certain audiences to feel unnecessary discomfort.

Comment: I initially downvoted because, yes, "chink" is a slur, but then checked Mordy's profile and say they're from the UK, where maybe it isn't used as a slur, so I took it back, but I'd echo maxathousand's comment.

Comment: On reflection, perhaps it is necessary for language to modify once words become so abused that they lose their respectable meaning. Which is why medical professionals, when about to inject a patient say, 'Just a little scratch' instead of the expression they used to use.

Comment: @NigelJ What did they used to say?

Comment: I'd think of 'gap' when I hear chink, to the point where the word would not 'fit'

Comment: @NigelJ I think this issue is aggravated here since the term doesn't really fit the situation.  "Chink in [his] armor" is basically the only phrase  in which I expect to hear this term.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor, they would use Prick.  I still hear "pin prick" in the US, but I _think_ in the UK prick is more exclusively a phallic related insult.

Comment: @JPhi1618 'prick' can still be legitimately used in any number of non-phallic applications in the UK. People still suffer pin pricks, pricks of conscience, they still prick out their seedlings, fences still get specified with prick-posts... And the only situations where 'chink' could by any stretch be a source of confusions between a slur and a word describing a sound of a gap would be the aforementioned 'chink in his armour', but given tit always follows  the introduction of the vulnerability to which it relates, there is no sensible sentence which would be truly ambiguous on that score.

Comment: Wow...I really don't know what to say.  Downvoted for a racist slur...I'll just clarify before I delete my account on here.    chink  (chĭngk)
n.
A slight, metallic sound, as of coins rattling in a pocket.
intr. & tr.v. chinked, chink·ing, chinks
To make or cause to make a slight, metallic sound.

Comment: Strange to me that so many folk who purport to have some expertise in English would be so concerned about a word without any context.  The context of "racist chink" is significantly different than the context of chink in this question.  Should we not say that a cell culture was retarded by a medium because "retarded" can be a mean thing to say about someone with intellectual difficulties? Context, context, context.

Comment: "Chink" in context can either be racist, or totally acceptable. After all, no one gets upset if someone says "chink in his armor". Obviously that is not meant to mean an Asian person stuck inside the cracks in some guy's armor...

Comment: @maxathousand "Bitch" is not commonly used (outside of those who breed dogs), anymore than "cunt" is used nowadays to refer to a rabbit (which is its origin). However, there are plenty of better analogies. You definitely can use the term retard without offending people, just like you can say "Dick Van Dyke" without making phallus references or offending lesbians. To compare the word chink to the word bitch is really stretching it.

Comment: @forest I was only intending to make the OP aware of this alternate meaning.

Comment: @maxathousand I was referring to your second comment, not the first one which just brought up the fact that some people may find it offensive in certain contexts.

Comment: @forest Sure. I’m sorry, my intention was not to bring into question whether or not words with offensive alternate usages should be used or not, but rather to inform OP that this alternate definition even existed. If they were unaware, I don’t believe it’s a stretch to imagine that it be used in a way that does not adequately provide context. As a quick example, “*...awoken by a loud chink...*” is ambiguous and could cause an audience discomfort that could have been easily avoided. :)

Comment: @maxathousand https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Ns9djGa-7I

Answer (score 10):

Sound of coin hitting the jar full of coins or other coins in the jar is called  **jingling**. 
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jingle

> a light ringing sound that is made when metal objects hit each other.

It is obvious that coins are metal pieces.

Excerpt from wiki:

> This design allowed coins to be put in the bottle but not allow them to be removed easily without the coins jingling against the glass. wiki: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Street_performance

**Note**: it is not specifically related only to coins.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, but _jingling_ makes me think of shaking the jar full of coins, probably because of jingles on a tambourine, or Jingle Bells and Christmas songs.

Comment: @isanae plz check definition of jingle.

Comment: There's a difference in sound between two suspended metal objects hitting each other and one metal object hitting a pile of other metal objects. I don't think _jingling_ is correct for the latter.

Comment: @isanae there is no connotation of suspension in the definition of jingle.

Comment: @isanae can you provide connotation of suspension in the definition of jingle?

Comment: The Merriam-Webster definition is incomplete because it doesn't mention the fact that "jingle" suggests a multitude of little sounds rather than a single sound.

Comment: @ubihatt At least in the US, jingle is strongly associated with chimes or bells, which are generally hung or attached to a surface. The most common use of jingle with coins is to "jingle your change" meaning to shake or toss some loose coins in your pocket or hand. Jingle in this case is not wrong per se, but it usually implies a repeating deliberate sound, rather than a one-time incidental sound.

Comment: @ubihatt the suggestion of suspension comes from the definition of a 'ringing sound'. Coins don't very much 'ring'. 'Ringing' is a ' resonant or vibrating sound', which isn't much what you get when you drop a coin onto a heap in a jar. You get a much duller sound, more of a small clatter.

Comment: I got a little change in my pocket going jingle-lingle-ling... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AMFMf9cN64U

Answer (score 8):

Use "clink" when there are few coins and/or the jar is resonant.  Pitch = high.  Use "jingle" again where there are few coins.  "Jingle" is (often) associated with "pants pocket."  Pitch = high.  Use "clunk" when the impact -- such as it is -- generates little sound because (a) the mass of coins below is large enough so that it does not respond and/or (b) the jar is heavy, or nearly full, and likewise does not react much.  Pitch = low.  You could avoid the construct by instead using "plunk," a verb meaning "to drop or toss one more thing onto a pile of things."

Answer (score 4):

Alongside *jingle*, there is also *jangle*, which intimates a more discordant metallic sound:

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jangle

> 1. to make a harsh or discordant often ringing sound
>
> *keys jangling in my pocket*
>
> 1a.  to cause to sound harshly or inharmoniously

Answer (score 3):

*Roget's Thesaurus* has a selection of suitable words in **403: Repeated and protracted sounds** and **404: Resonance**; as these are mostly onomatopoeic, choose that one that sounds closest to your experience:

- rattle
- clatter
- clang
- tinkle
- jingle
- chink
- clink

Section **405: Non-resonance** has some that are less likely for a small jar of coins, but may suit a much bigger jar (say 25cm or greater in diameter).

Comment: Is there a link to section 405 referred to here?

Comment: I'm not sure how to provide a link to a book - just grab it off the shelf and turn to that section.  As I say, it's unlikely to be what's required for this question, which is looking for more resonant sounds.

Comment: I would do it by Googling: http://www.roget.org/scripts/categoryxref.php?inputstring=405

Answer (score 0):

How about clank? It has the same meaning to me as clink - a sound or series of sounds of metal on metal.

Comment: Nah, clanking is *big* (usually metal) things, like gears, parts of an engine, or objects moving around in the boot (UK) or trunk (US) of your car (UK) or automobile (US). Not completely bad, it's mostly about the tone (large solid jar, big heavy coins, might clank, but clink seems more appropriate to the pitch of your usual coin-coin plus coin-jar collision sounds.

Answer (score -2):

Cha-ching which is also the classic cash register sound

Comment: Yes, but that's the sound of old mechanical tills opening and the bell ringing. It's not the sound of coins rattling together.

Comment: Hi Mr. N! Welcome to EL&U please take the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and read through the [help centre](https://english.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Cha is the coin hitting the container, Ching is the coin hitting other coins

Answer (score -9):

Since clink, clank, chink, jingle, and jangle just don't "ring true" to me in this context, I'm going to suggest going metaphorical.  You could say something like, "My heart warms a little every time I hear the gentle "sprinkle" of fresh coins landing on the pile in my coin jar."

I can't complete this answer without mentioning the fact that the timbre of the sound of "coins landing on other coins" is dependent on the material in which the coin pile is contained, and your word choice could reflect that fact.  I might use "tinkle" or "sprinkle" for that sound coming out of a glass container (piggy bank, coin jar), and I might use "clang" or "jangle" for that sound coming out of a metal box (vending or slot machine's coin box, or a collector bin in a coin mint).

Comment: As much as I appreciate most of the other answers, this one distinguishes itself by going metaphorical - I like that. The other suggested words I have seen before (searching around), while the ones suggested here are new and interesting. That's kind of what I looked for. Thanks! Of course, as I'm not a native english speaker, I don't have the "feeling" for the associations one can have with the words "sprinkle" and "jangle", so please fill in in the comments what you think about them.

Comment: @LukasKalinski You asked for the "common name" for the sound, then accepted an answer with one upvote that is, at least in AmE, most definitely not the common name for that sound.

Comment: This is doesn't seem to match the question.  I don't see anything about literary flourish.  The question just asks what the sound is called.

Comment: In addition to the already mentioned issues with this answer, the word 'sprinkle' is not, to my knowledge, a name for a sound.

Comment: @LukasKalinski you should either edit your question, or accept a different answer. No one *in everyday talk* (as requested by your question) says "the coins made a gentle sprinkle as they fell into the jar" or anything to that effect. If you do like this answer for its uniqueness, you should rephrase your question to omit the "common name" and "everyday talk" portions, otherwise this answer does **not** answer your question as written.

Comment: Ok ok, I get what you mean. I have reconsidered which answer to pick as the correct one, and I did that based on number of upvotes (as I'm unable to know myself which word is the best fit).